# Pressing ENTER after clicking an object in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click an object and press ENTER.
I have tried the below way but having an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'"

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH").click()
    a.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'"
```

Comment: the `.click()` function returns None. You need to set `a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")` then click on it and press enter separately.

Answer (score 0):

`.click()` method does not return a web element.
You can change your current code to make it working as you wish as following:

```py
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")
a.click()
a.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```